# Is the role of the boxed condition $z'(t)\neq 0$ to avoid going back?

Tags: complex-analysis, curves, complex-integration, plane-curves

[image]

The role of the boxed condition $z'(t)\neq 0$ is to avoid going back, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is so that the velocity is never $0$, which implies that we can parametrize the curve by the arc length. It also implies that $z\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$ has no “corners”, which corresponds to the idea of a *smooth* curve.